# Distinguishing between columns with UTC and local datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server, utc

I work on an application that stores datetimes in a SQL Server database. Some of these are a point in time stored in UTC (such as log item datetimes), while others are a literal date/time (such as "take medication X at 4pm on 20 July, irrespective of your timezone).

Problem is that these both have a date and time component, so using a datetime2 column type makes sense for both. We're now in a situation where it is often unclear in our app whether a date/time column is a UTC point in time or a literal date/time.

What is the most common practice to distinguish between these 2 cases? I can think of these options:

1) End all UTC columns in ...Utc, while literal date/time columns have no special ending.

2) End all literal columns in ...Literal, while UTC date/time columns have no special ending.

3) Give UTC columns the data type datetime2 and literal date/time columns datetimeoffset.

Comment: can you alter the table and add a new column? eg. a flag column `isUTC` that shows you whether it is a UTC time or not...

Comment: I've seen #1 quite often (and use it myself).  I've not seen #2 "in the wild".  I would not suggest #3

Answer (score 0):

Always try to use the appropriate type first and then good naming. If `datetime2(0)` is a good fit, use it.

In my system I add a suffix to the column name, for example: `PlaybackStartedLocal datetime2(0)`, `PlaybackStartedUTC datetime2(0)`. In my case I have to store both local and UTC values for the same event, because some reports need local value, some UTC and it is very difficult to convert between them later.

In general it is a good practice to include units of measurement into the column/variable name.

What do you prefer to see:

```
PlaybackDurationMSec            or    PlaybackDuration
LengthMeters / LengthMiles      or    Length
```

A well-known example when two teams of programmers didn't notice that they were interpreting metric values as imperial and visa versa: [A disaster investigation board reports that NASA’s Mars Climate Orbiter burned up in the Martian atmosphere because engineers failed to convert units from English to metric.](https://www.wired.com/2010/11/1110mars-climate-observer-report/)

> The software calculated the force the thrusters needed to exert in
>   pounds of force. A separate piece of software took in the data
>   assuming it was in the metric unit: newtons.